# Mandrill search email result

Tags: c#, api, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I am curious can I search the result of whether an email bounced or not using the mandill api in c# .net
I know this can be acheived using webhooks but dont know how to do that.
basically I want to search the result by supplying an email id and finding out whether it was a hard bounce or soft bounce or successful.
if so please post the code.
thanks,
Tommy

Answer (score 1):

First, there are several [c# wrappers](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738166-API-Wrappers) available for Mandrill. Which one you want to use is up to you and how it fits your needs.

Second, of course there is a way to see if a message is hard bounced or soft bounced. The Mandrill API for [Message info](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info) contains all the details regarding the status and bounce description.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cant do the search by mail id but there is an _Id which is related the mail being sent through the mandrill api send method.

[image]

and now with that id you can search the message details if you want details about particular mail

```
MandrillApi Api= new MandrillApi(key);
Info info = new Info();
info.key = key;
info.id = _Id;  // which is the id of the just sent mail
var list = Api.Info(info);
```

which will results this where you can see the state of message whether its being sent or bonced

[image]

or if you want to search entire messages and know the details of each message then you can come up with some thing like this

```
        Mandrill.Search search = new Mandrill.Search();
        search.senders = new string[] { "vivekh.meka@live.com" };
        search.key = key;
        MandrillApi Api= new MandrillApi(key);
        var searchs = Api.Search(search);
```

and then you can go through the individual message by looping it

```
foreach (var x in searchs)
        {

            Info info = new Info();
            info.key = key;
            info.id = x._id;
            try
            {
                var list = Api.Info(info);

            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {

            }
        }
```

and not to forgot i have changed the api method's myself as i found that they are not working for me
you can download the cs project [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1856raz1lni9bz2/Mandrill.rar?dl=0) add it as an existing project and can call the api methods